# Storing / Deleting mp3 Files on a website

Tags: php, mysql, mp3

I have a website were I would like admins to be able to upload mp3 files for other users to view and download. I would also like for the for the admins to be able to remove those files. I have thought about storing the files into mySQL databases (BLOBS) but apparently that's a bad idea and I should just use a DB to reference the mp3 files (artist, album etc).

How do I upload / remove files stored in a folder on the server using php (and mySQL)?

Answer (score 0):

1 - During upload, rename mp3 to a unique name (ex: user_id + unixtime) and save it to a folder.

2 - Save the full path (ex: /home/user/mp3/userid_12345678.mp3) on mysql, associated with the user_id.

3 - When you want to delete, get a list of files (full path for each file) and then use:

```
# extract path from mysql to $mp3 variable
if file_exists($mp3) { 
unlink($mp3); 
} else { 
echo "File $mp3 not found."; 
}
```

4 - Upload: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_file_uploading.htm